# React native: No android folder exist after installing react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am beginner in react native and i m using expo to create react native project .

In my test application i want to use [react native maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps).

After [installing](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md):

```
npm install react-native-maps --save-exact
```

There is no `android` project in my test project for **Build configuration on Android**!!!!

[image]

But the map shown in application:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Platform
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const region = {
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
}

export default TrackingScreen = props => {
    return (
        <View>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                region={region} />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    map: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use `react-native-maps` if you are using `expo` coz expo doesnt allow linking of native modules. So you have 2 options , either eject from expo to bare react native and use `react-native-maps` or try maps of expo [expo-maps](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/). there you have to do `expo install react-native-maps`

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts

Comment: Thank's bro.I have a question? Now i installed map by `npm install react-native-maps --save-exact` and not `expo install react-native-maps` although i am using expo then why i can see my map in my application: http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=d755f833ffadb761bf58e670de6fce88 @GauravRoy

Comment: Yes as you can see on picture http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=d755f833ffadb761bf58e670de6fce88 @Gaurav Roy

Comment: then whats the problem now?

Comment: I did not insert google key or do any configuration? I read anywhere and they wrote about configuration and so on!!! but i did not any configuration  @GauravRoy

Comment: read the docs of this once https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/ .  you will getr to know

Comment: Thank bro but in . https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/ at Configuration part ‍‍‍‍`If you already have not configured Google Sign In` part 8 in my app.json does not exist `android.package`  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/THBytSBKmW/ ? @GauravRoy

Comment: usually there is a android:{ } like the ios you have in package.json

Comment: This is my package json: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ckxV97RSqD/  and there is not `android.package` inside it  like app.json @GauravRoy

Answer (score 0):

You have only installed the React Native Maps package, you still need to link it to your Android project. See the following instructions: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#build-configuration-on-android

Comment: Ok, but how could i link my react project ? android folder dose not exist  @Mish

Answer (score 0):

If you project is Expo Based then use below command

```
expo eject
```

Then you have to give package name for android project like com.example.am

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
react-native eject
```

Command to create `iOS` and `Android` folder into `react-native` project.

Comment: I created project by expo like `expo init testproject`. Now where `react-native eject` must be executed? inside my project folder ? @Sunny

Comment: @sayreskabir Yes

Comment: Read more info about ejecting the app before using a react-native eject command.

Comment: please dont eject , just for the cause of adding android and ios directory, if you eject. Then it will change a lot of things because you wont be able to go back to expo , like  it was, either it will change to bare react native or an expo wrapper. @MohamedSameer is right